# Enable style button on ribbon in SP 2010 edit list form

Tags: list, ribbon

I am trying to add custom styles to a wysiwyg editor field in a SharePoint list.

I have tried adding in the prefix .ms-rteStyle-xxxxx (xxxxx being the style name). This still doesnt seem to get picked up and the style button in the ribbon remains disabled.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use custom styles in a list item text box and if so how do you go about enabling the styles button.

Thanks,
Lynden